# Postfix wildcard alias for DOMAINS

Tags: postfix

Is there a way to use an wildcard for the domainname, like

```
webmaster@*
```

Wildcards for addresses on a domain are working with "@domain", but "hostmaster@" does not work.

current setup with *@domain wildcard:

main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

virtual (wildcard for `domain`, one mailadress for `domain2`):

```
domain anything
domain2 anything
@domain user@localhost
mail@domain2 user2@localhost
```

and now i want to have some standard addresses for every domain, like

```
webmaster@ user3@localhost
```

But this syntax does not work in that way. One option would be to add the address to each (non-wildcard) domain by hand, another option may be to use a `pcre` map for the virtual table. But using a pcre-table for aliases seems too unclean and adding them by hand is what i want to avoid.

Comment: For which address class? For `local` address class, the alias expansion will happen for the `username` part of the email address already. Can u be more specific about your requirement?

Comment: i added some details of the current setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you'd want to use a [regexp type map file](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) and then you could do something like

`/^webmaster@/ user3@localhost`

If you want to keep the existing hash virtual file as well I suppose the config directive would be something like

`virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regex`