# Postfix: Alias from multiple adresses to one

Tags: email, postfix, vps, forwarding

I've installed a postfix/dovecot combination on my VPS the last days and everything works fine. Now I want to add mail forwarding, so that mails with a specific suffix, like this:

- youtube-**account@mydomain.tld**
- reddit-**account@mydomain.tld**
- stackexchange-**account@mydomain.tld**
- *-account@mydomain.tld

are forwarded to one adress like **accounts@mydomain.tld**. I manged to forward all mails that go to *@mydomain.tld to a specific one, but that doesn't do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you tried regexp alias map? http://serverfault.com/questions/585103/postfix-wildcard-alias-for-domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a way by myself. There may be a better way to do this, but this one is done pretty quick and it works fine. I simply use the address tagging feature, which already comes with Postfix.

After I created the *account@example.com* email address in my postfixadmin panel, I edited the **/etc/postfix/main.cf** file:

```
recipient_delimiter = -
postfix reload
```

... and that's it. Now every mail that's sent to *account-*@example.com* will be forwarded to *account@example.com*

You can also replace the "minus" (-) with every other character.